# Factorial simplication question

Tags: factorial

How does the following:

$$(k+1)! - 1 + (k+1).(k+1)!$$
simplify to:

$$ (1+k+1).(k+1)! - 1 $$

and then

$$(k+2)! - 1$$

I just can't seem to see how that works, I've tried writing out the factorials in the form:

$ (k+1)(k)(k-1)....$ and looking at in this way but it still isn't clicking.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Factor out the $(k+1)!$ term.

Comment: Wow I'm stupid.

Was having one of them moments, thank you!

Comment: Rather than period for multiplication, you could use \cdot to get a centered dot:  $\cdot $

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
(k+1)! - 1 + (k+1)(k+1)!
&= 1\cdot(k+1)! + (k+1)\cdot(k+1)! \\
&=\big((k+1)+1\big)\cdot(k+1)!-1 \\
&= (k+2)(k+1)! - 1 \\
&= (k+2)! - 1.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Factor out $(k+1)!$ from the first equation. Then it should easily follow.